# How to solve a system of linear equation when the first column is all $0$s?

Tags: matrices

I want to solve this:

$$\left[ \begin{array} {cc} 
0& 1 \\
0& 0 
\end{array}\right] 
\left[ \begin{array} {c} 
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{array} \right]=
\left[ \begin{array} {c} 
0 \\
0
\end{array} \right] $$

My attempt:

First, I interchange the columns of the matrix so that it is in echelon form:

$$\left[ \begin{array} {cc} 
 1& 0\\
 0& 0
\end{array}\right] 
\left[ \begin{array} {c} 
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{array} \right]=
\left[ \begin{array} {c} 
0 \\
0
\end{array} \right] $$

Then, I note the first row corresponds to the following equation:

$$x_1 + 0x_2 = 0$$
So, $$x_1=0$$

Therefore, the solution is:
$$
\left[
\begin{array} {c}
0 \\
0
\end{array}
\right]
+t\left[
\begin{array} {c}
1 \\
0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Is this correct and is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution does not correspond with your reasoning. Look at the original equation. It says that $x_2=0$. However, you argue that $x_1$ must be $0$, which is not correct. Your solution is correct, because there $x_2=0$ and $x_1$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Can you please show me the correct steps to arrive at the correct solution? I don't understand why $x_1$ can be arbitrary

Comment: Well, if you write out the equations you'll see that the first one is $x_2=0$, and the second one does not give you any information. Just try any value for $x_1$ and you'll see that the matrix equality is satisfied as long as $x_2=0$.

Answer (score 2):

no. If you  interchange the columns of the matrix then you must interchange variable. (put $x_2$ "over" $x_1$)

by the way, the first matrix is alreay in a echelon form. You can solve the system directly from that. Getting $x_2=0$.

Also, the last step contains a mistake because  from $x_1=0$ you deduce that $(1,0)$ is a solution, which is a contradiction.

You made two mistakes that cancels so the final answer is correct, bur in an exam this counts as two mistakes.

Comment: Can you please show me the correct steps to arrive at the correct solution? I thought one of the conditions for echelon form means the first column must contain a leading 1.

Comment: it depends on the definition of echelon form

Comment: anyway, if you want to exchange columns you must exchange the variable according to the columns you exchanged